Why do I generate Zig Zag lines instead of a surface when attempting to plot a contour plot in latex using csv data?
I am trying to generate a contour plot from a the following csv file unCon01new10.csv.
When I generate the contour plot using Mathematica it looks like .
When I try using the same csv file to generate a contour plot using Latex the plot looks like  and I don't know why.
I failed looking for a solution online. Hence why I am here. Below is the latex code that generates the latex image. (Any suggestions on how I can make the Latex contour plot look like the Mathematica plot?)
Latex code:
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90}, % Adjust the viewing angle
        colormap/viridis, % Choose a colormap
        colorbar, % Show a colorbar
    ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            mesh/check=false, % Disable the check for now
        ]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, z index=2, col sep=comma]
        {./unCon01new10.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Just in case you are interested, here is the Mathematica code that generates the first image.
Mathematica code:
(*(*Clear previous definitions to avoid shadowing issues*)
Remove["Global`*","MaTeX`*"];

ClearAll["Global`*","MaTeX`*"];*)

(*Load MaTeX package*)
<< MaTeX`

(*Configure MaTeX with proper paths*)
ConfigureMaTeX[
  "pdfLaTeX" -> 
   "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\\
x64\\pdflatex.exe", 
  "Ghostscript" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs10.03.1\\bin\\gswin64c.exe"];

(*Import data*)
tupleListImport = 
  Import["path_to_file\\unCon01new2.csv"];


(*(*Define a function to use MaTeX for text rendering*)
latexStyle[text_]:=Style[MaTeX[text],Medium,Bold,Black]*)

(*Generate the plot*)
p2 = ListContourPlot[tupleListImport, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# <= 0.1, 0, 1], 
       ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][#]] &), 
   AxesStyle -> Thick, 
   FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\theta", FontSize -> 20], 
     MaTeX["\\phi", FontSize -> 20]}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, FontSize -> 20], 
   ImageSize -> 400, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed}, PlotLegends -> Automatic];

(*Display the plot*)
p2


Welcome to TeX.SE.  Can you also post the first ~10 lines of unCon01new10.csv?
